# Recover data from Synology JBOD/Linear RAID disks

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, synology

I have a two disk synology where I had a JBOD setup (4TB and 3TB). One of the drives started becoming erratic and failed. So I pulled both of them out.

I had an automated daily backup task that would backup my important folders from disk1 to disk2.

I'm trying to gain access to both these disks from a ubuntu PC. (Connected the two 3.5inch DISKS into a Dual slot USB dock that connects to a ubuntu laptop via one USB 3 port.

I've tried to follow the instructions from synology link below, but it doesn't work.
https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC

Here is the output of some of the commands:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md3 : active linear sdc3[0] sdb3[1]
      6827740928 blocks super 1.2 64k rounding

lvs
  LV                    VG  Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  syno_vg_reserved_area vg1 -wi------- 12.00m                                                    
  volume_1              vg1 -wi-------  2.72t                                                    
  volume_2              vg1 -wi-------  3.63t       


lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
(truncated some of the loops)
loop17    7:17   0 161.4M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
sda       8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk   
├─sda1    8:1    0   100M  0 part   
├─sda2    8:2    0 146.4G  0 part   
├─sda3    8:3    0     1K  0 part   
├─sda5    8:5    0   158G  0 part   
├─sda6    8:6    0  13.9G  0 part   [SWAP]
└─sda7    8:7    0 380.3G  0 part   /
sdb       8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk   
├─sdb1    8:17   0   2.4G  0 part   
├─sdb2    8:18   0     2G  0 part   
└─sdb3    8:19   0   2.7T  0 part   
  └─md3   9:3    0   6.4T  0 linear 
sdc       8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk   
├─sdc1    8:33   0   2.4G  0 part   
├─sdc2    8:34   0     2G  0 part   
└─sdc3    8:35   0   3.6T  0 part   
  └─md3   9:3    0   6.4T  0 linear 

mount /dev/vg1/volume_2 /home/user/synology/disk1 -o ro 
mount: /home/user/synology/disk1: special device /dev/vg1/volume_2 does not exist.

mount /dev/vg1/volume_1 /home/user/synology/disk1 -o ro 
mount: /home/user/synology/disk1: special device /dev/vg1/volume_1 does not exist.
```

Any advice on how to get this mounted correctly and access the data ?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I was able to fix this.

The steps in the link I included earlier worked just fine.

I had to follow the following steps to resolve this issue:

1. Reboot the ubuntu system.
2. change the boot order so it doesn't try to boot via USB
3. keep the Drives connected via USB before the boot starts.

Once booted, I did the mount command as suggested in the link and voila, the drives were then accessible.